# Implement an interface that is exposed by a component in a class inside the component and show it in the corresponding class model

Tags: class, interface, components, modeling, enterprise-architect

I have a Component in a component diagram that provides several interfaces. Now i'd like a class in a class diagram that describes this component to implement this interface.

What i tried:

- Drag the interface into the class model --> results in the message 'When dropping embedded elements to a diagram, you must drop them on theit correct owner.'
- Creating the interface in the class model, then trying to link it with the interface in the component model --> I didn't find a way to accomplish that.
- Adding the class to the component model and add a realization to the exposed interface. This results in pretty arrows, but the class is in the component model. If I remove it from the model, the interfaces are still in the linked element list of the class, but i have found no way to add the interfaces to the model then, neither show in another way that this class implements those interfaces.

Any proposals how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way DOES work. I now found the [...] button beside the textfield where to enter the name of the interface. It is possible to add an existing interface there.